# Using Element ID as Key Name When Accessing Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this object:

```
var prices = {
        monthly: {
            consumer: {
                pro: 99,
                threeSixty: 149,
                team: 249
            },
            business: {
                pro: 149,
                threeSixty: 199,
                team: 299
            },
            both: {
                pro: 199,
                threeSixty: 249,
                team: 349
            }
        },
        annual: {
            consumer: {
                pro: 79,
                threeSixty: 119,
                team: 209
            },
            business: {
                pro: 129,
                threeSixty: 169,
                team: 259
            },
            both: {
                pro: 169,
                threeSixty: 209,
                team: 299
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to be able to access values in it by using HTML element IDs as the key name. I obtain these IDs based on clicks. For example, I have these inside of a click function:

```
var billingType = jQuery('.active-billing-type').attr('id');

var packageType = jQuery(this).attr('name');
```

Which I would then like to use to access the above object data by doing this:

```
var newPrice = prices[billingType][packageType];
```

I am then trying to update HTML elements with the data I retrieve from the object, but it simply isn't working. I receive no console errors, just nothing happens. Suggestions? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Provided that billingType resolves to the value of a level one key, and the packageType resolves to a key under neigh that object, nothing you have provided would be invalid syntatically.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qchf2u4g/  So long as the variable values map to keys in the objects that they are accessing, it doesn't matter where those values come from.

Comment: They do resolve correctly, and I actually just figured it out. I had plural spellings on my click element IDs and non-plural in the object. So now I feel silly as I've been fighting with this for 30 minutes...